# How to set JSON Schema as a global variable in Postman?

Tags: json, postman

I want to validate the JSON schema against the response. For that, I set it as a global variable in Postman through UI. And it works perfectly fine.

Is there a way it could be set using pre-request script?

I tried defining the schema with quotes(string) and without quotes(object), but doesn't seem to work:

```
const schema = 
    "{
        "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
        "$id": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
        "title": "Core schema meta-schema",
        "definitions": {},
        "type": [
         "object"
        ],
      "title": "The Root Schema",
       so on...
     }"

pm.globals.set("globalSchema", schema);
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried is as an object but with `pm.globals.set("globalSchema", JSON.stringify(schema));` - You could the do a use `JSON.parse(pm.globals.get('globalSchema'))`. Not tried this so that's why i'm adding as a comment.

Comment: Yes, that worked! Please add it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be what you need to capture the `schema` object:

```
pm.globals.set("globalSchema", JSON.stringify(schema))
```

You could then use this to reference that value elsewhere:

```
JSON.parse(pm.globals.get('globalSchema'))
```

Comment: var globalSchema = JSON.parse(pm.globals.get('globalSchema'))